# Copy from Bitarray (not byte array) to a another Bitarray

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need to copy from Bitarray (not byte array) to a another Bitarray. `Bitarray1.CopyTo(Bitarray2, 26)` is not working, what is the correct method to do that.

Comment: Could you please show me your `Bitarray` declaration?

Comment: `Dim Bitarray1 As BitArray = New BitArray(ByteArray1)`

Answer (score 0):

CopyTo( destinationArray, StartIndex)  if you put 26 it will try to copy , from bit 26, you have to use 0 (bitarrays are always zero  based) to get everything from the start of the array
copyTo also only copys to an array , to get it back to a bitarray you have to create a new one

```
Dim AnArray as Array     
Bitarray1.CopyTo(anArray, 0) 
Dim BitArray2 As New BitArray(Anarray)
```

Comment: `CopyTo` does not take a `BitArray` argument.

Comment: I want to copy from 26th bit, that is intentionally written as 26 .. but still it doesn't work ..

Comment: sorry my mistake you have to copy to a Array not a bitarray

Comment: no, I need to copy from a Bitarray to a Bitarray, please read the title

Comment: edited and added the convertion from array to bitarray

Answer (score 0):

How about a plain old `for` loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Bitarray1.Length - 1
    Bitarray2(i + 26) = Bitarray1(i)
Next
```

Comment: yeah, I think I have to use the same old way ... I wonder why VS haven't add a method to copy from bitarray to a bitarray instead of to a array.